# Florence Pass for museum, historical places and public transport?

Tags: public-transport, tickets, italy, museums, florence

I plan to visit Florence, Italy during May. I would be staying in the city for 3 days, visiting all the places that worth a visit, and do it in a cheap manner.

So I wonder whether is there a "Florence Pass" for museum, historical places and public transport, that would allow me to save some of my money?

Comment: Even with the Firenze Card card the lines can be long, way to many people have a "Skip the Line" pass. The exception is the Pitti Palace, with the Card just go to the head of the line and to get the actual ticket. If you take a tour they do bypass the lines. I took the Duomo Terraces Tour and we went right in a seperate door. If you are going to ride the busses or tram gat the bus add-on the the Firenze Card.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [Firenze Card](http://www.firenzecard.it/). It costs €50.

It gives 3-days access to most places worth to visit in Florence and to public transport.

About public transport, Firenze is not that big: everything is at walking distance, even from Santa Maria Novella train station. I wouldn't recommend to go downtown by car.

Most historical places, mainly churches, are entrance free. Some places, like the Duomo, are equipped with pay-for-light machines.

Comment: Note that the use of busses is an add on to the Firenze Card you have to pay for,  I saw a couple get tickets on the #12 bus, they were surprised because they had a Firenze Card.